Choosing optimal and best components for surge protector
There is a plug type surge protector I'm trying to design and I want varistors to resist the surge protected plug when there is a high transient voltage spike above 275-300 VAC coming from mains power. If the voltage spike is too high for varistors there is a GDT to direct the load  to the earth. I have a circuit designed and attached its drawing here. I just want to choose the optimal value of varistors, GDT and fuses. There is a normal 16 A fuse through the Line node and 2 temperature dependent fuses. Varistors' storage temperature is max. 125℃. I'm really confused on selecting GDT and  varistors. S20K275 MOVs have 710V clamping voltage. And I selected 800V+-%20 DC Spark-over voltage GDT. However it may still short the circuit because %20 tolerance rate may interfere with 710V clamping voltage of S20K275 and S20K300 MOVs.
Datasheet values and the circuit design is attached.




Are you trying to keep total voltage below 300 VAC on a a 220 VAC line? If so, regrettably, MOV devices don't have a very sharp conduction knee, and might not draw enough current to quickly blow that 16 amp fuse at just 300 VAC.

This is an awful lot of work for one LED. Is that really all the load will be? If so, there are MUCH simpler (and more reliable) solutions.

You generally put the GDT up front. It can survive a bigger kick than the varistors.
